# How to write variables as binary data with Python?

Tags: python

I need to write a long list of ints and floats with Python the same way `fwrite` would do in C - in a binary form.

This is necessary to create input files for another piece of code I am working with.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use the `struct` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at numpy: [numpy tofile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile):

With the array-method 'tofile' you can write binary-data:

```
# define output-format
numdtype = num.dtype('2f')

# write data
myarray.tofile('filename', numdtype)
```

Another way is to use memmaps: [numpy memmaps](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

```
# create memmap                                              
data = num.memmap('filename', mode='w+', dtype=num.float, offset=myoffset, shape=(my_shape), order='C')
# put some data into in:
data[1:10] = num.random.rand(9)
# flush to disk:
data.flush()
del data
```

Comment: This is a simple and effective solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need dtype as the argument to 'tofile'. Actually the file is incorrect if I do so

Answer (score 5):

You can do this quite simply with the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

For example, to write a list of 32-bit integers in binary:

```
import struct

ints = [10,50,100,2500,256]
with open('output', 'w') as fh:
    data = struct.pack('i' * len(ints), *ints)
    fh.write(data)
```

Will write `'\n\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\xc4\t\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00'`